# Java application - which all parts of my code are being fired up in production?

Tags: java

I have a java web based application running in production. I need some way to be able to see which all parts of the code is being actually used, by the actions of the end user.

Just to clarify my requirement further.

1. I do not want to put a logging based solution. Any solution that needs me to put some logs and analyse the logs is not something that I am looking from.
2. I need some solution that works on similar lines like unit test coverage reporter. Like cobertura or emma reports, after running the unit tests, it shows me which all part of my code was fired up by the unit tests. I need something that will listen to JVM in production and tell me which all parts of my code is being fired up in production by the action of end user.

Why am I trying to do this? 
I have a code that I have inherited. It is a big piece - some 25,000 classes. One of the bits that I need to do is to chop off parts of the application that is not being used too much. If I can show to management that there are parts of the application that are being scarcely used, I can chop off those parts from this product and effectively make this product a little more manageable (as in the manual regression test suite that needs to run every week or so and takes a couple of days, can be shortened).

Hope there is some ready solution to this.

Comment: Why not use the exact same tools you use for test coverage?

Comment: Are you able to elaborate any more on what problem you're trying to solve? This sounds like a bit of a strange thing to be doing, so I wonder if explaining further might get a more useful response?

I know you say you don't want a logging-based solution, but from what you've said here, that sounds like the most appropriate answer. Could I ask why it is that you don't want to add logging?

Comment: With VisualVM you could profile your app, take a snapshot and then export the result for further analysis. I don't know if that fits your needs but you should be able to cover the basics. (method invocations, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

As Joachim Sauer said in the comments below your question: the most straightforward approach is to just use a Code Coverage Tool that you'd use for unit testing and instrument the production code with it.

There's a major catch: overhead. Code Coverage analysis can really slow things down and while an informed user-base will tolerate some temporary performance degradation, the whole thing needs to remain useable.

From my experience JaCoCo is relatively light and doesn't impose much overhead, whereas Cobertura will impose a *tremendous* slowdown. On the other hand, JaCoCo merely flags "hit or no hit" whereas Cobertura gives you per-line hit counts. This means that JaCoCo will only let you find dead spots, whereas Cobertura will let you find rarely hit spots.

Whichever of these two tools you use (possibly one after the other), you may end up with giant class whitelists and class blacklists to restrict the coverage counting to places where it makes sense to do so, thereby keeping the performance overhead down. For example, if the entire thing has a single front controller Servlet, including that in the analysis will maximize the performance overhead while providing no information of value. This could turn into a lot of work and a lot of application deployments.

It may actually be quicker and less work to identify bottlenecks/gateways into specific subsystems and slap a counter on each of those (e.g. [perf4j](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) or even a full blown Nagios). Queries are another good place to slap a counter on. If you suspect some part of the application is rarely used, put a few counters there and see what happens.

Comment: Nagios - Too elaborate. Won't do for me. 
perf4j - Good suggestion for getting a grip on performance of suspected code. But that is not what I am looking for here. 
Cobertura - Too slow. But would do my job for the moment. I know how to use that in unit testing paralance. But I dont know how to use that in production. Any document / tutorials? 
JaCoCo - Better than cobertura. I need to know only the classes that are not called at all. But I dont know how to use that in production. Any document / tutorials?

Comment: Just to elaborate further - I know how to instrument code of production and get coverage data - but I know that the output file is not written till the application server is shut down. How do I get around that? I don't want to stop the application server to get the coverage data.

Comment: I've never tried any of that, but from a quick look at the source code, their agent package has an [MBean](http://eclemma.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/eclemma/jacoco/trunk/org.jacoco.agent.rt/src/org/jacoco/agent/rt/controller/MBeanController.java?revision=1563&view=markup) that contains a `dump()` method returning a byte array. This looks like it might be what you need.